# How do I remove this effect?

Tags: 14.04, unity

Whenever I hover over the title bar, it collapses and shows all windows. I find this really annoying and don't know how this got enabled. How do I disable this thing?

Before hovering:
[image]

After hovering on top title:
[image]

It happens immediately and automatically. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally enabled a Hotcorner. It's very easy to disable this. Just a few clicks, in fact.
Open your terminal and type in `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`. Once it installs, open it and click on 'Hotcorners', under the Window Manger section. Make sure all of the hotcorners are disabled.